# Class 'Db' not found

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

When I attempt to connect to my SQL database with my pdo_object.php file, my model.php returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Db' not found in /path/model.php on line 8
```

I made sure all of the permissions are correct and credentials are correct for all of my files. Here are the two files in question.

Not really sure what the issue is here so any help would be awesome.

pdo_object.php

```
<?php
    $user = 'someusername';
    $pass = 'somepassword';
    $db_info='somehost';
    try {
        $db = new PDO($db_info, $user, $pass);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }


    ?>
```

and then model.php

```
    <?php
include('pdo_object.php');

 class Model{
    public $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = Db::getDb();
    }

    public function getAllRecords($sql, $parameters = null){
        $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute($parameters);
        return $stm->fetchAll();
    }

     public function getOneRecord($sql, $parameters = null){
                $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stm->execute($parameters);
                return $stm->fetch();
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: where you found Db class ? how are you using `$this->db = Db::getDb();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `class Db { //blah }`? Nowhere. But you HAVE defined `$db` in the first file.

I also recommend dependency injection, rather than calling static class methods inside your class. Essentially, pass the $db in in the constructor:

```
public function __construct(PDO $db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

And instantiate like so:

```
$model = new Model($db);
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually solved my issue. It had to do with the pdo_object.php file not having the correct information inside, so the index.php file was referencing a class that did not exist. I will be posting an answer.

Comment: good stuff! you should pass in an array with the credentials though rather than hard coding them in

Comment: That's honestly a really good idea. I will use that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The Db class was not present in the `pdo_object.php` file, thus resulting in the `index.php` file throwing an error when referencing a non existing class.

```
class Db {
      private static $db;
      public static function getDb() {
        if(!self::$db) {
          try {
            $dsn = 'somehost; dbname=somedbname';
            self::$db = new PDO($dsn, 'username', 'password');
            self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
          } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage());
          }
        }
        return self::$db;
      }
    }
```